# Poder enviar un motor de plantilla (en este caso Handlebars desde Node) a Angular por medio de una peticion get

Tags: nodejs, angular, express

quiero saber si es posible enviar un archivo .hbs (un motor de plantilla) que tengo desde en Backend de mi aplicacion para renderizarla en una peticion get y la quiero mostrar desde el Frontend en angular, quiero saber si esto es posible?, No he encontrado nada relacionado a esto y ya lo he intentado y me salen errores, no se si esto se pueda

Lo que tengo en el Back como respuesta a la peticion get que contiene el renderizado de la plantilla handlebars:

```
router.get( "/" ,get_bingo )

const get_bingo = async( req=request, res=response )=>{    
    res.render("index");
}
```

Lo que tengo en el front para recibir esa respueta, intente lo mismo con el .subscribe() pero igual me genera error :

```
await this.api.get("http://localhost:8080/api/bingo").then((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
      
    }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err);      
    })
```

El error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:46736:41) at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8236:171) at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:58413:49 at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask
```

Tambien intente parsear la respuesta a un formato Json y tampoco me deja enviarlo asi

La configuracion de la plantilla:

```
this.app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Lo que tengo en el documento .hbs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hola</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: De ser posible, es posible, ¿has intentado algo? Por cierto bienvenido a SOes, recuerda realizar el recorrido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas cómo es la dinámica del sitio, lee también https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Para aumentar las chances de obtener respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Buenas, para que sea más fácil responder vendría bien saber qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora. Podrías dejar tu código.

Comment: @Ouariachi                                                                                                           
hola ya deje el codigo, agradeceria cualquier ayuda o comentario, Gracias!!

Comment: Cuando haces la llamada http en angular tienes uqe indicarle que lo que va a obtener no es json: `this.http.get(URL_A_LA_QUE_LLAMAS, {responseType: "text"})`. Con esto podrás obtener la respuesta como html puro e inyectarla en donde te apetezca